# how to enable C++11 or C++14 in Dev C++ IDE

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, dev-c++

I'm trying to compile this on Dev C++ IDE, but it's showing this error :

```
error This file requires compiler and library support for the

  ISO C-+ 2011 standard. This support is currently experi Ical, and it be emblem with the -stdest or -stdagno 11 compiler options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow these Steps in DevC++.**

Got to **Tools** -> **Compiler Options...** -> **Settings** -> **Code Generation**

[image]

In **language standard**(std), choose -> **ISO C++11**

[image]

more https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-auto-keyword-error-in-dev-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

Form **softwaretestinghelp** [Q #2) Does Dev C++ support C++11?](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/dev-cpp-ide/#:%7E:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20click%20on%20Tools%20in%20Dev%2DC%2B%2B%20IDE.&text=Under%20this%20click%20the%20%E2%80%9CSettings,11%E2%80%9D%20as%20per%20your%20requirement.)

- To do this, click on **Tools** in Dev-C++ IDE.
- Next click on **Compiler Options**…
- Under this click the “**Settings**” tab.
- Inside the settings tab, we can see the “**Code generation**” tab.
- Click on the “**Language Standard (-std)**” value and set it to “**ISOC++11**” or “**GNUC++11**” as per your requirement.

**The screenshot below will help in actually changing the option.**
[image]